# Bigger points in AndroidPlot

Tags: android, graph, androidplot

Follows up to [Custom points on graph using AndroidPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169080/custom-points-on-graph-using-androidplot)

We are trying to make the points on a graph (A SimpleXYPlot from AndroidPlot) larger so that the graph can be read more easily. It doesn't seem like there's a simple setting for this, and the answer in the question above involves making a custom renderer, which seems like overkill.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the size by setting the stroke width of your LineAndPointFormatter's vertex paint.

Programmatically:

```
formatter.getVertexPaint().setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(20));
```

via XML (using Configurator):

```
vertexPaint.strokeWidth="20dp"
```